# Project management: Implementing custom errors in VS compilation process

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, enforcement

**AGAIN: If you're voting -1, please leave a comment explaining why. This post isn't about whether or not you approve if this approach, but how to go about it.**

Like many architects, I've developed coding standards through years of experience to which I expect my developers to adhere.

This is especially a problem with the crowd that believes that three or four years of experience makes you a senior-level developer.Approaching this as a training and code review issue has generated limited success.

So, I was thinking that it would be great to be able to add custom compile-time errors to the build process to more strictly enforce our in-house best practices and coding standards.

For instance, we use stored procedures for ALL database access, which provides procedure-level security, db encapsulation (table structure is hidden from the app), and other benefits. (Note: I am **not** interested in starting a debate about this.) Some developers prefer inline SQL or parametrized queries, and that's fine - on their own time and own projects.

I'd like a way to add a compilation check that finds, say, anything that looks like

```
string sql = "insert into some_table (col1,col2) values (@col1, @col2);"
```

and generates an error or, in certain circumstances, a warning, with a message like

`Inline SQL and parametrized queries are not permitted.`

Or, if they use the var keyword

```
var x = new MyClass();
```

`Variable definitions must be explicitly typed.`

Do Visual Studio and MSBuild provide a way to add this functionality? I'm thinking that I could use a regular expression to find unacceptable code and generate the correct error, but I'm not sure what, from a performance standpoint, is the best way to to integrate this into the build process.

We could add a pre- or post-build step to run a custom EXE, but how can I return line- and file-specifc errors?  Also, I'd like this to run after compilation of each file, rather than post-link.

Is a regex the best way to perform this type of pattern matching, or should I go crazy and run the code through a C# parser, which would allow node-level validation via the parse tree?

I'd appreciate suggestions and tales of prior experience.

**Comments**
Several respondents have pointed out that it's possible to restrict the ability of a user to run anything but a stored proc through db permissions. However, we're in the process of porting a 350k+ line application from ASP 3.0 to ASP.NET MVC, and the existing code base relies pretty heavily on concatenated SQL, whereas the new stuff all uses Enterprise Library. I guess I could add a separate web user account for the .NET code with more restrictive permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For coding standards I would look at writing custom rules for FxCop or StyleCop.  I don't think Regex would be a suitable tool for the job.

For the specific case of requiring Stored Procedures - if you ensure the application doesn't have permission to do anything else on the production database, everyone will soon fall in line.

Comment: +1 for the DB permissions suggestion, but even restricting access to stored procedures only still allows creation of concatenated SQL such as "exec my_stored_proc '"+val1+"','"+val2+"'" which is less than ideal. Also, can I force StyleCop or FxCop to run? I suppose I could do it on the source control server. Hmm.

Comment: "I suppose I could do it on the source control server" - probably the best way, you probably don't want to incur the performance penalty of code analysis on every build.  I think it would be possible to create an FxCop rule that flags attempts to call ADO.NET methods with CommandType set to anything other than CommandType.StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 1):

What about writing a plugin for Resharper? Here is a tutorial to start with: [Writing plug-ins for ReSharper: Part 1 of Undefined](http://hadihariri.com/blogengine/post/2010/01/12/Writing-plug-ins-for-ReSharper-Part-1-of-Undefined.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Implicit typing (`var x = ....`) is a feature that can be turned off on project level in visual studio.

The other one is trickier. Have you had a look at FxCop, which is the tool for enforcing code standards.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement that only stored procedures can be used should be managed through database permissions. The rule against using var seems fairly arbitrary to me and I can't think of a way to enforce it. Do you have any more examples of your best practices?